# Open submenu at the same position

Tags: html, css

I made a submenu with HTML and CSS. What I want is for the submenu to open at left:0 and span the entire width of the screen. I cannot use the position as fixed as it causes a clash with the sticky. I achieved what I wanted by manually adjusting the position of the submenus. However, I want to know the right way to do this for optimization and smoothness

```css
.main-navbar{
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-flex;
    background-color:white;
    top: 3.7rem;
    width: 100%;
    height: 4.5rem;
    align-items: center;
}

.logo img{
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 11.1rem;
    left: 9%;
    margin-top: 0px;
    width: 330px ;
    transition: 0.1s ease-in-out;
}

nav{
    display: inline-flex;
    width: 100%;
    align-items: center;
}
.nav-list{
    font-size: 1rem;
    display: flex;
    margin-top: .7rem;
    margin-left: 2.7rem;
}

.nav-list li{
    position: relative;
}

.nav-list > li > a{
    color: black;
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.05rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    padding: 1.3rem 1rem;
}

.nav-list > li > a::after{
content: "";
position: absolute;
background-color: red;
height: 4px;
width: 0;
left: 0;
bottom: 1px;
}

.sub-menu {
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: white;
    visibility: hidden;
    top: 3.83rem;
    left: -34.465rem;
    width: 100vw; 
    height: 35rem;
}

.sub-menu a {
    position: relative;
    font-weight: 200;
    padding: 3rem 40px 0 40px;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}


#submenu2{
    position:absolute;
    left: -38.595rem;
  
}
.nav-list>li:hover .sub-menu {
    visibility: visible;
}

.nav-list>li:hover>a::after {
width: 100%;
   }
```

```html
<div class="main-navbar" id="navbar">
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="https://static.nike.com/a/images/q_auto:eco/t_product_v1/f_auto/dpr_2.0/w_441,c_limit/9d1635ed-eed0-45b0-b34d-e00468e2f79e/tanjun-easyon-shoes-mplG1H.png" alt="">
  </div>
  <nav>
    <ul class="nav-list">
      <li class="dropdown-item-1">
        <a href="men.html">Men</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li><a href="#">shirts</a> </li>

        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown-item-2">
        <a href="#">Women</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu" id="submenu2">
          <li><a href="#">shirts</a> </li>

        </ul>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Pay a bit more attention, please - with the typo `main-navbar` in your first rule's selector, your snippet here (once again ...) didn't even properly show the issue. (Fixed it already for you.)

Comment: `.nav-list li{ position: relative; }` - that makes the parent li of the submenu, the reference point for the latter's absolute positioning. So remove that, then you can simply position the sub menu at `left: 0`. (And if you remove the `width: 100vw`, and set `right: 0` instead, you will also not have to deal with 100vw probably being more than what's needed, if body paddings or a scrollbar come into play.)

Comment: But i the position as relative

Comment: Why do you need to parent li to be relative?

Comment: For the .nav-list > li > a::after

Comment: Give the `a` position relative instead then, and position the pseudo element correctly regarding that.